# With styled-components in React JS, what is the more preferred way to add conditional styling?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Sample code (code example from *Learning React*, pp 146-150);

Note that different from the book, which was written two years ago, I am trying to implement the same functionality using styled-components. In the book, the CSS is all done inside of app.css and the Star component looks like so:

```
const Star = ({ selected=false, onClick= f=>f }) =>
  <StyledStar className={(selected) ? "selected star" : "star"}
    onClick={onClick}>
  </StyledStar>
```

and the app.css look like so:

```
.star {
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
  clip-path: polygon(
          50% 0%,
          63% 38%,
          100% 38%,
          69% 59%,
          82% 100%,
          50% 75%,
          18% 100%,
          31% 59%,
          0% 38%,
          37% 38%
      );
}



.star.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

As you can see, if the star is selected, it appears as red instead of grey.

I'd like to refactor this using styled-components, and here's what I've tried:

// star.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledStar = styled.div`
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  background-color: ${`this.props.selected ? 'grey' : 'red'`};
  clip-path: polygon(
          50% 0%,
          63% 38%,
          100% 38%,
          69% 59%,
          82% 100%,
          50% 75%,
          18% 100%,
          31% 59%,
          0% 38%,
          37% 38%
  );
`

const Star = ({ selected=false, onClick= f=>f }) =>
  <StyledStar className={(selected) ? "selected" : ""}
    onClick={onClick}>
  </StyledStar>

Star.propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func
}

export default Star
```

for some reason the interpolation I am expecting in `` background-color: ${`this.props.selected ? 'grey' : 'red'`}; `` doesn't work, and my ternary conditional comes out in the CSS as I wrote it in JavaScript.

Am I missing something? I thought could interpolate inside of the styled div like this but I guess not?

I also tried this

```
const StyledStar = styled.div`
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  background-color: grey;
  clip-path: polygon(
          50% 0%,
          63% 38%,
          100% 38%,
          69% 59%,
          82% 100%,
          50% 75%,
          18% 100%,
          31% 59%,
          0% 38%,
          37% 38%
  );

  .selected {
    background-color: red;
  }
```

... but I couldn't get that to work either. (Unlike SCSS, which I am familiar with, you can't see to 'nest' your CSS declarations inside of a styled block, no?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In styled components functions passed to interpolations are called with the `props`. You can destructure the `props` to get `selected`:

```
const StyledStar = styled.div`
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  background-color: ${({ selected }) => selected ? 'grey' : 'red'};
  clip-path: polygon(
          50% 0%,
          63% 38%,
          100% 38%,
          69% 59%,
          82% 100%,
          50% 75%,
          18% 100%,
          31% 59%,
          0% 38%,
          37% 38%
  );
`
```

Usage - pass the prop to the styled component in the same way you pass `onClick`:

```
const Star = ({ selected = false, onClick = f => f }) => (
  <StyledStar
    selected={selected}
    onClick={onClick}>
  </StyledStar>
)
```

Comment: well it's a stateless component so do props exist on my Star? The `selected` flag is passed in direclty

Comment: hmmm… the interpolation works correctly but all my stars are red (selected)

Comment: @JasonFB you also need to pass the `selected` prop down to your `StyledStar`.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see `StyledStar` is like its own object(?). I got it working. Your answer is in fact perfect except that you have red and grey reversed (the selected state should be red and the non-selected state should be grey). When changed to `${({ selected }) => selected ? 'red' : 'grey'}` it works as expected. thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I've copied the colors from your example :)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from styled-components docs:

> Interpolation: This can either be a **string** or a **function**. Strings are combined with the rules as-is. Functions will receive the styled component's props as the first and only argument.

Your component's interpolation should be a function:

```js
const StyledStar = styled.div`
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
  background-color: ${props => props.selected ? 'grey' : 'red'};
`
```

Alternatively you can make this much cleaner by passing the function at the top level:

```js
const StyledStar = styled.div(
  props => `
  /* props can be accessed from the above props */
  color: ${props.color};
  background: ${props.selected ? 'grey' : 'red'};
`
)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sc-props-ppsij)

EDIT: fixed typo

Comment: `background-color: ${props => props.selected ? 'grey' : 'red'};` works as expected

Comment: your example `styled.div(props => ` causes a syntax error. it has no opening backtick. where does the opening backtick go, before or after the `(`. I've spent a lot of time with the (very confusing and difficult to digest) styled-components docs, and I never saw this syntax

Comment: since you provided two alternative solutions, could you please answer the question in the post: "What is the more preferred way…"   One issue I have with this ecosystem is that there appears to be 4 ways to do anything and nobody can agree on when or why to use what syntax.

Comment: `const StyledStar = styled.div`(props => `  this syntax causes the javascript of the inline style to be spat out onto the browser, not correctly compiled into CSS. I am downvoting because this second answer is completely misleading, causes a "Failed to compile" message, I cannot seem to get the syntax righ ton repeated attempts, and I see no mention of creating a Styled Component with explicitly passing in 'props' into this pseudo-function

Comment: as far I can I can tell only the functional method works `${props => props.selected ? 'red' : 'grey'};` … the non-functional implementation does not work and I cannot get it to work whatsoever `${props.selected ? 'grey' : 'red'};`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I just fixed it and included a link to the example.